# How to bind value datetimepicker

Tags: angular, bootstrap-datetimepicker

html

```
<input
type="text"
name="startTime"
class="datetimepicker"
value="{{pointTravelInput.startTime}}"
#startTime="ngModel"
[(ngModel)]="pointTravelInput.startTime"
autocomplete="off"
required>
```

ts

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
    language: "th",
    format: "dd-mm-yyyy hh:ii:00",
    defaultTime: 0,
    todayBtn: true,
    autoclose: true,
    orientation: "top",
    startDate: new Date()
   }).on("hide", (e) => {
  });
});
```

when I selected date it not working
`pointTravelInput.startTime` not bind the value. How do I solve it?

Comment: Try not use jquery with angular. Try https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker as it uses component design which is better suited for angular

Comment: Thank you i gonna try it after waste much time with JQuery

Answer (score 2):

You should stop using `$(document).ready` when you are using angular...

Angular makes use of specialized methods which are called on certain moments while the angular application is being rendered. The one you will need (to start with) is the `ngOnInit`.

My advice for you, as it seems you came from a JQuery background, is that you take some time and go though the [Tour Of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial) tutorial form Angular.

That should help you get started.

Comment: Not sure if its an answer or should it be put as a comment

Comment: i moved it in to **ngOnInit** but its seem not work because the templete not finish yet

Comment: to use JQuery in the Angular template, you need to call it after the view is rendered.  You can try to use the hook `ngAfterViewChecked()` https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: Thank you its seem work in `ngAfterViewChecked()` but i still can't bind value with **datepicker** or **date type**

Comment: Using JQuery, you will not be able to bind the value without some customization.... try to find an alternative without using JQuery.

Comment: so we sholud use JQuery with angular or not ? @TheFabio

Comment: try to avoid using JQuery as much as you can. otherwise you will have to customize angular a fair bit to handle JQuery (specifically changes on inputs data can be hard to do)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
<input type="date" name="startTime"
              class="datetimepicker" [ngModel] ="pointTravelInput.startTime | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="pointTravelInput.startTime = $event" [value]="datee | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'"  autocomplete="off"
              required>
```